# Solve the recurrence $A_N = 1 + \frac{2}{N} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq N} A_{j-1}$ for $N > 0$ by quicksort???

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

$A_N = 1 + \frac{2}{N} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq N} A_{j-1}$  for $N>0$

I have tried only one step which is multiply the equation by $N$,

i.e. $NA_N = N + 2 \sum_{1 \leq j \leq N} A_{j-1}$,

then I'm lost.

Would anyone like to continue solving please? I'm really confused about quicksort and recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick to deal with recurrences that have a sum involving the previous term is to subtract two instances of the recurrence. Here, we have:

\begin{align}
   NA_N &= N + 2 \sum_{j=1}^N A_{j-1} \\
   (N-1)A_{N-1} &= N-1 + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} A_{j-1} \\
NA_N - (N-1)A_{N-1} &= 1 + 2\left(\sum_{j=1}^N A_{j-1} - \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} A_{j-1}\right) \\
      &= 1 + 2 A_{N-1}.
\end{align}
This gives us the recurrence $NA_N - (N-1) A_{N-1} = 1 + 2 A_{N-1}$, which we can simplify to $NA_N = 1 + (N+1)A_{N-1}$ or (slight hint) $\frac{A_N}{N+1} = \frac{A_{N-1}}{N} + \frac1{N(N+1)}$.

See if you can take it from here.

Comment: Shouldn't the 1 be 1/(n)(n+1) ? Why is it only 1/n?

Comment: It absolutely should be; that's my mistake.

Comment: And a magic telescope appears.